# How to invoke different methods from parameters in Java?

Tags: java, function, lambda, functional-programming

Assume that I have a method A and B from a class:

```
List<String> A(int start, int size);
List<String> B(int start, int size);
```

Now, I have another function that might use A or B. But before invoking them, I'll do some logic first:

```
void C() {
 // lots of logic here
 invoke A or B
 // lots of logic here 
}
```

I want to pass method A or B as parameter of C, something like:

```
void C(Function<> function) {
 // lots of logic here
 invoke function (A or B)
 // lots of logic here 
}
```

However, I noticed that the Function class in Java can only accept one parameter (method A or B both have two parameters). Is there a workaround on this? (I don't want to change the method A or B signatures).

Comment: Sure.  Use `BiFunction`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. BTW, what if method A and B has different return types (List<String> vs List<Integer>) ? Does this still work?

Comment: Use Lambdas. The only change would be function A and function B would be an implementation of an abstract function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BiFunction` represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a result, so you may want to look into that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

Comment: Thanks, BTW, what if method A and B has different return types (List<String> vs List<Integer>) ? Does this still work?

Comment: @injoy try generalising your method to `<T> void C(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, List<T>> function) {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use and write your own functional interface by lambda expression. I illustrate here,

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    List<T> f(int start, int size);
}

class Example {
    List<String> A(int start, int size) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    List<Integer> B(int start, int size) {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    void C(MyInterface function) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        MyInterface<String> methodForA = (x,y) -> e.A(1,2);
        MyInterface<Integer> methodForB = (x,y) -> e.B(1,2);

        e.C(methodForA);
        e.C(methodForB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a method reference instead of a lambda?

Comment: @vandench I don't have enough knowledge yet about _method references_